# When and where angular create the object of component class?

Tags: angular6

I am new in angular, so please avoid if this is silly question.

When we create a component then 4 files generated.

```
1.  Component.ts
2.  Component.html
3.  Component.spec.ts
4.  Component.scss
```

We defined a class with member variables and methods in .ts file. If we need to display value of class’s member variable then we put that variable in .html file using {{ **member_variable_name** }}.

As I see, we don’t initialized the class anywhere in our component but value of **member_variable_name** render on the html page.

So how class member variable value display on component.html page without making object of that class? When and where angular create the object of this class.

Comment: Typically, whenever you have `<my-component></my-component` in a view (where my-component is the `selector` of the component) in a template. Or when you use the router to navigate to a route that is configured with that component. This is fundamental angular stuff. It's not a bad question, but it should be answered by reading the documentation or a good book, not by asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Angular instantiates the instance of the component class automatically.

"When you bootstrap with the AppComponent class (in main.ts), Angular looks for a `<app-root>` in the index.html, finds it, instantiates an instance of AppComponent, and renders it inside the `<app-root>` tag."

Details: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: Thanks for quick response Bro.